# Do I have to write a privacy policy if i'm using unity analytics or unity advertisement or facebook sdk

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games, privacy-policy

I have set up unity analytics and unity advertisement and Facebook SDK on my android game, I have published it several times and it got suspended two times, I don't want to risk anymore so I wanted to know if I should write a private policy telling the users why I use unity and stuff? 
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a privacy policy, but you don't necessarily have to write one yourself. On the Unity forums, if you're using Unity Analytics and Unity Ads, they recommend using the following link for your privacy policy when publishing to the Google Play Store:

https://unity3d.com/legal/privacy-policy

I use it for my game, and I've never had a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this comment will help someone,
google has changed their policy and now REQUIRE that your apps name (or organizations name) be included in the privacy policy, so basicly you have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's pretty clear in [Facebook policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) that you need a Privacy policy:

> 4. Privacy Policy
>
>    a. Provide a publicly available and easily accessible privacy policy that explains what data you are collecting and how you will use that data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm actually a newbie, Is there any examples or guides to writing a  policy? I will use the Facebook SDK for retargeting and the lookalike stuff

Comment: We blogged about some examples of Privacy Policies that have clauses regarding Facebook retargeting here -- https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-facebook-retargeting/ -- Hope this helps.